Not able to open another modal after submitting the Slack Modal from AWS Lambda after data submission. Using slack bolt and Javascript
Not able to open another modal after submitting the Slack Modal from AWS Lambda after data submission.
The code is -
app.action({
    type: "block_actions",
    action_id: /^pending_task_action_(\d+)$/
  },
  async ({
    ack,
    body,
    client
  }) => {
    await ack();

    const selectedOption = body.actions[0].selected_option.value;
    const selectedApplicationId = body.actions[0].block_id;
    const userEmail = body.user.name + "@test.com";

    // Open a modal with a text input for reason
    await client.views.open({
      trigger_id: body.trigger_id,
      view: {
        type: "modal",
        callback_id: "reason_modal",
        private_metadata: JSON.stringify({
          selectedOption,
          selectedApplicationId,
          userEmail
        }),
        title: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: ":wave: Please comment ",
        },
        blocks: [{
          type: "input",
          block_id: "reason_input",
          element: {
            type: "plain_text_input",
            action_id: "reason",
            multiline: true,
          },
          label: {
            type: "plain_text",
            text: "Please provide comment for your action:",
          },
        }, ],
        submit: {
          type: "plain_text",
          text: "Submit",
        },
      },
    });
  }
);

Here the next quick modal is not getting opened.
// Handle submission of the reason modal
app.view('reason_modal', async ({
        ack,
        body,
        view,
        client
      }) => {

        await ack();
        // Open a quick loading modal
        const initialModal = await client.views.open({
          trigger_id: body.trigger_id,
          view: {
            type: "modal",
            title: {
              type: "plain_text",
              text: ":man-biking:Processing..",
            },
            blocks: [{
              type: "section",
              text: {
                type: "plain_text",
                text: ":hourglass_flowing_sand: Please wait while we process your request...",
              },
            }, ],
          },
        });

Tried sending response acknowledgement but didn't worked.
Cannot directly close the reason_modal as i have to show other modals as well after main comment modal.
